# Generated WCF SOAP client uses current user for windows authentication instead of given credentials

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-6.0, wcf-security

I'm kind of new to the whole WCF and SOAP topic so please be kind.

I'm using a generated SOAP Client with .net6. In another project we successfully worked with the same Web Service using the old .net Framework 2.0 Web References and the same credentials.

Strange enough everything seemed to work fine at first. Until I realized, that it does not use the given credentials to authenticate. Instead it authenticates with my own domain user.
I also tried to get it to work with explicitly setting the binding with a `BasicHttpBinding` but I only could get the same broken logic to work or I got various authentication/protocol/security errors.

So it seems the authentication is basically working. It just doesn't use the provided credentials. So my question is: How can I configure it to work with the provided identity?

I also found out that it might have anything to do with a cached Windows token. But how can I get rid of it. How to prevent caching in the first place?

EDIT:
Specified the variable types explicitly.

```
string url = "http://someServer/AdministrationService.asmx";
AdministrationServiceSoapClient client = new AdministrationServiceSoapClient(
    AdministrationServiceSoapClient.EndpointConfiguration.AdministrationServiceSoap,
    url);

WindowsClientCredential credential = client.ClientCredentials.Windows;

credential.ClientCredential.UserName = "username";
credential.ClientCredential.Password = "password";
credential.ClientCredential.Domain = "DOMAIN";

GetServerInfoRequest getServerInfoRequest = new GetServerInfoRequest
                               {
                                  // some stuff set here
                               };

GetServerInfoRequest getServerInfoReply = await client.GetServerInfoAsync(getServerInfoRequest);
```

Comment: Windows Authentication *does* mean using the current user's account. This way you don't have to specify or store passwords. That's the whole 
 point. If you don't want that, don't use Windows Authentication.

Comment: What you describe as "strange" is how things always worked in .NET, IIS, ASP.NET and WCF. Which means going back to 2002. When Unix and Linux systems had to build and use single-sign-on, Windows app and services simply configured a domain account and added it as a permitted account to the services it needed to access. That's equivalent to eg using an IAM account in AWS except it works out of the box

Comment: As for `.asmx`, that's not WCF. WCF never used that suffix. When WCF services used a suffix, it was `.svc`, never `.asmx`. ASMX is the suffix used by the ASMX Web Service stack that was replaced by WCF in 2006. It has several quirks simply because WS-* standards hadn't been published yet, but it *does* work with Windows or Basic authentication

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos 
Thanks for your ideas. Actually I just want to access a SOAP Service that worked perfectly well with a really old .net Framework 2.0 SOAP Client. The service is an API of a Software we are using and that is relying on Windows Authentication. I never said that the Server is WCF. I'm currently only working on the client side.
I'm not interested in criticising windows authentication. I just need a solution to authenticate myself on a SOAP Service with a different windows account.

Comment: @Dai Added the types according to your hint. Thank you. Unfortunately the theory about the defensive copy was wrong. It gets written to the actual instance of the client. Explicitly writing the credentials object doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After waiting a day it is working. It seems that the cached credentials became invalid somehow.

Strange enough the simple service creation from above is not working anymore. Instead I have to use the following.

```
var client = new AdministrationServiceSoapClient(
    new BasicHttpBinding()
    {
        Security = new BasicHttpSecurity()
                   {
                       Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly,
                       Message = new BasicHttpMessageSecurity()
                                 {
                                     ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName,
                                 },
                       Transport = new HttpTransportSecurity()
                                   {
                                       ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows,
                                       ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.Windows,
                                   }
                   },
    },
    new EndpointAddress(url));
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, BasicHttpBinding has security disabled by default, but can be added setting the BasicHttpSecurityMode to a value other than None in the constructor. It can be configured according to the instructions in [BasicHttpBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) and [BasicHttpBinding Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#system-servicemodel-basichttpbinding-ctor(system-servicemodel-basichttpsecuritymode)).

By default, setting up client credentials involves two steps: determining the type of client credential required by the service and specifying an actual client credential, as described in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/securing-clients).